# Limiting RAM usage with prlimit

Tags: ram, memory-usage, resource-limiting

I need to run a program not written by me (i.e. BLAST) on linux (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS), and I need to set the limit for RAM usage for this specific case, since I am working on a shared cpu. Also, I would prefer not install or use scripts developed from other people. I thought I could use prlimit, something like:

```
prlimit --pid xxxx --rss=yyy
```

But I'm not sure --rss is the right parameter to limit the RAM usage, because I'm new in this field and I'm a bit confused about the different options reported in the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/prlimit.1.html). Also, I don't know how to express such a limit, I didn't find anything about it (I would need to set the RAM limit to around 300GB).So, I took a look to older related questions, but I still have these doubts.

I also read replies to other questions suggesting ulimit, but as far as I understood, this applies limits to the current user (while I would like to set the limit not for my specific user, but only for the specif process that I'm running at the moment).

**EDIT**

I tried to use the command:

```
prlimit --memlock=1024 --rss=1024 --pid xxxxxx
```

with the limits set to 1024, just to see if it worked, but it doesn't. My process do not get killed. Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Any alternative solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Hello, I edited the question, the version is Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 3):

Generally when I need to do this with a process as a once-off, I’ll [use `systemd-run`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/systemd-run.1.html) with some limits in place:

```
systemd-run --scope -p MemoryMax=300G {program or script}
```

This will [use `cgroups` to effectively manage the resources](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/cgroups.7.html) afforded to the process *and any child threads*. Although the command will ask you for your password, the process runs under your user and does not make use of `sudo`.

Comment: @DougSmythies `cgroups` are wonderful things 

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, it looks a really elegant one. Unfortunately, I do not why, but it asks for the password of the main user (even if I am logged with my profile). Do you know any other solutions which does not require it?